# Using Windows Forms Web Browser in ASP.Net

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, azure

I have a problem authenticating against Sharepoint Project Web App, from my ASP.Net app. One of the last tricks in my pocket that could work is taking a web browser from Windows Forms package, and performing an auth in it. This browser will be hidden from the user, will use service account to authenticate and will populate some JSON from PWA once a day. I will emulate the normal authentication you go through if you login to PWA with your browser.

This feels a bad idea to me, but if I do not have any other options, I might go with it. The problem is that I can't really explain exactly why it is bad, thus my question.

What possible problems should I expect doing this? ASP.Net app will be hosted in Azure, we also do an auth on Azure.

Comment: is there any reason why you can't use windows authentication and check a users role \ group in SharePoint?

Comment: @SimonPrice All the examples I've seen doesn't work and I've asked this question a few times everywhere including SO. I think it is because it is not normal SharePoint, but also PWA

Comment: ok, so what have you tried so far? SharePoint if deployed correctly will have SSO built in to work with AD and Groups

Comment: How do you intend to host your ASP.NET app in Azure? App Service? Cloud Service? VM with IIS? For App Service at least you are going to have a problem running anything that requires UI. The Win Forms web browser uses a lot of windows dlls that dependes on a window so it probably wont work.

Comment: @SimonPrice I have a working code that successfully acquires a BearerToken and can get information from our Sharepoint Online, but not from PWA. My suspiciion that PWA has a second layer of security which I cannot overcome

Comment: Another option could be a headless Selenium web driver. You should be able to run that directly from your ASP.NET app.

Comment: @SimonPrice You can have a look at my question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41719686/accessing-sharepoint-project-web-app-rest-from-separate-app

Comment: @yoape Thanks, that is one of the worries I have too. It is also the first thing to try out when I get to it. Selenium web driver might work, but I need to research more

Comment: @Archeg if you want I can send you some selenium code that does something similar (logs in to a site and pulls down data) using a headless web driver that runs on an App Service, or try to put it in an answer.

Comment: @yoape I would very much appreciate that

Comment: @Archeg ill be at my computer in a couple of hours, post it then an hope it will help you get started. Happy to help

Comment: For those who are interested and to @yoape: I've used the idea yoape given, about using headless browser, but I've used https://github.com/HtmlUnit/NHtmlUnit instead. This one seems to work better for me as I don't have to run any executables (Selenium Webdriver uses browser drivers, that come as executables). I still have to test how it will work on Azure, but I assume there should not be any problems.

Comment: @Archeg HtmlUnit should work fine for you, I had some issues with automating sites with *very* advanced javascript in, but in most cases it should do the job, and as you say, a lot easier than running Selenium web driver. Especially now that GhostDriver (to use with PhantomJS) is not maintained anymore. Would be awsome to hear more of your findings.